# Unable to launch Android Emulator

Tags: android, linux, netbeans, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I am using Netbeans 8.1 and android-sdk for Linux, *without* a GPU. When I run my project, or when trying to *Start* the emulator, I am getting:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'MG'
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 512MB
emulator: ERROR: GPU emulation is disabled.
Only screen size of 768 X 1280 or smaller is supported when GPU emulation is disabled.
```

The Details are:

[image: AVD emulator]

Any ideas *please*?

---

Edit:

Same behavior if I try from cmd with:

> gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~/android-sdk-linux/tools$ ./emulator -avd MG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is clearly stating that

> Only screen size of 768 X 1280 or smaller is supported when GPU emulation is disabled.

As I can see in the image you have attached you are using virtual Nexus 5 in your MG AVD which has 1080 x 1920 screen size.

Change your hardware profile to Nexus 4 or create custom AVD having resolution 768 x 1280 or less.

Comment: Nexus 4 is the solution! Thank you.